# While knowing another Jew will mechalel shabbat because of you, is it preferred you do it instead?

Tags: shabbat, grama

So I have a general question:

If you are a religious Jew and you are in a non religious Jew's home on Sabbath and you mention that it is really hot and you would love to have an AC on and then you see your non religious friend reaching for the remote to turn on the AC. Should you do it instead of him? After all if not you technically caused a "גרמא בשבת" which was your fault and so the "chilul Sabbath" is on both of you. You for causing him to do it, him for doing it.

What is the ideal way to deal with such a situation?

Comment: Why not just ask him not to turn it on?

Comment: @DoubleAA Asking him to turn it off can result in him doing it on purpose just to prove something because he knows deep down I want it but at the same time I am obeying the shabbis halachot.

Comment: Is that worse? You can't control him. Just be clear and consistent about what you want. If he sins it's not your fault.

Comment: Well it still is because it a grama I caused. Especially since I knew that me telling him would just make him want to do it more.

Comment: I don't think you understand what Grama means and how it functions in Hilkhot Shabbat

Comment: From what I learned a "grama beshabbat" is when you cause something to happen on shobbis that is muktze. The gmara brings up the idea of asking a goi to do mechalel shabbat for you and they say that even there you have to make sure you are not being straight forward about your request. So when it comes to a fellow Jew you need to be extra careful!

Comment: I think that may be different levels of the violation. You're doing the melacha directly seems to be a higher level than your friend doing it. But again, even in this scenario, at the point that you see your friend reach for the remote, I think you have an obligation to tell him NOT to turn on the AC. If your friend turns it on, anyway, it's a different story.

Comment: @DanF but if he sees it as a challenge this is your fault according to the rules of grama. Again - Especially because you know he will turn it on if you say something.

Comment: I was right. You don't understand the rules of Grama at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA Can you explain what I said that doesn't match the rules of grama?

Comment: All of it. It's almost like you looked up the word in a dictionary and made up rules for its use in halakhic discourse. Have you ever seen it in a Gemara? How was it used?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes I have seen it in the Gemera. It is used to describe a situation where a person is not the direct cause of a certain situation. The examples given are in Nizikin where if a person put is stuff on a roof and an animal ran by and knocked them down and it hurt someone in any way who is to blame? In masechet shabbat they also bring an example of a person who put pots of water on the sidewalk and when a fire reached the pots and the water from the ports turned off the fire is he to blame for causing this since it is a isur in the 39 melachot.

Comment: OK so then why would you think it applies in the case above where your friend is consciously doing the melakha himself?

Comment: @DoubleAA Because you caused it. You got him to even think about it. Obviously this could of been avoided but it wasen't and you in fact in a way caused him to turn it on. So that is why my question was if it is better if you just do it knowing that no matter what he will do it?

Answer (score 1):

So I have found a simple answer:

There is a concept in halacha that "אין שליחות לדבר עבירה"  because everyone is responsible to keep mitzvoth in their own right. Therefore if someone acts on his own you are not responsible. If however that person is not knowledgeable and is not familiar with halacha you could be over on "lifnei iver lo titain michshol" which is not the situation.

And so in light of what I mentioned above, The religious Jew has a responsibility to tell the non religious Jew to not mechalel shabbat and if he did, it is 100% his fault because he has to keep mitzvot and he is aware of what he is doing.

Thank you all for your responses and answers! =]

Comment: Please source your answer. It confirms one of my comments, above, with just further explanation that is unsourced, for the moment. And, since you mentioned a Grama aspect (I'm not commenting on the discussion between you and DoubleAA, as I still don't understand "gramma" even after the discussion), if, in light of your own answer, that aspect doesn't apply at all, I suggest that you delete it from your original question.

Comment: An important caveat: if you know he will mechalel shabbat regardless you have made a rebel out of him with the explicit warning. At first he could be regarded as a tinok shenashba. If you tell hem while you know he will disregard it, his status is that of a rebel

Comment: Better he should be shogeg than mezid --not always good to warn him.

Comment: @RonP but how can you know? Wouldn't it be better to warn him? His being a rebel is once again not your fault.